# Error Code 1005: Can't create table myTable (errNo: 150)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create this table in mySQL and i am getting 1005 error.

Any one can help me with this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(
    Id varchar(128) NOT NULL ,
    Email varchar(256) NULL,
    EmailConfirmed bit NOT NULL,
    PasswordHash text(65535) NULL,
    SecurityStamp text(65535) NULL,
    PhoneNumber text(65535) NULL,
    PhoneNumberConfirmed bit NOT NULL,
    TwoFactorEnabled bit NOT NULL,
    LockoutEndDateUtc datetime NULL,
    LockoutEnabled bit NOT NULL,
    AccessFailedCount int NOT NULL,
    UserName varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    UserId bigint AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL primary key,
    Name varchar(50) NULL,
    ZipCode int NULL,
    CountryId bigint NULL,
    IsDeleted bit NULL,
    CreatedDate datetime NULL

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Work for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05831

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and got the table created without any modification.

Regarding Error Code 1005, the MySQL documentation mentions a possible "foreign keys issue":
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html .

> Cannot create table. If the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed. If the error message refers to error –1, table creation probably failed because the table includes a column name that matched the name of an internal InnoDB table.